# Get intellij python to autocomplete on tab instead of space (and tab) which is does now

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete

Is there a way to prevent intelli(Idea) pycharm plugin from not autocompleting on space; I want autocomplete only when I hit the tab. 
Space to me means I want to continue typing without being bothered.

E.g. I'm trying to say something like d = 0.
Idea forces me to escape. A space will autocomplete to delattr.

[image: Intellij autocomplete]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable "Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion | Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc", then only Enter and Tab will choose the selected item in autopopup completion.